# Trying to import between multiple JS files

Tags: javascript, class, webpack, import, export

I'm creating a Todo app and I am using webpack to bundle multiple js files. I'm having trouble importing my functions and classes between the different js files. I keep receiving the error "SyntaxError: cannot use import statement outside a module.". I have set the entry in the webpack.config.js file to the index.js file. I can import from all the other js files into the index.js file and it works. Where I am having trouble is importing between all the js files themselves. I am fairly new to webpack and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

This is the task.js file code that I am trying to import into the ui.js file.

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export class Task {
  constructor(title, description, dueDate) {
    return Object.assign(this, { id: uuidv4(), title, description, dueDate, completed: false })
  }
}
```

Here is the code in the ui.js file

```
import { Task } from './task.js';

const taskOne = new Task('Hello', "goodbye")

console.log(taskOne);
```

Here is the webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
    assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Todo App',
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/template.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading a guide like [this](https://flexiple.com/javascript/javascript-require-vs-import/) one to understand the difference in js between require() and import. Without your code it is difficult to tell you exactly what is wrong and what you should do.

Comment: Hey @chill389cc, I updated the post my code.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with webpack so I'm not sure what the right route to go is. You could definitely replace your `import` and `export` statements with more traditional `require()` and `exports.foo` statements, but that might not be the best route. There might be a way to tell your project that you want to use ES6 module syntax, but I don't know how to do that.